# SQL how I can add an integer to the row number?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi guys I hope you can help me on below code to return a column with the row number plus 1 ,

```
with max_num as (..)
select 
    a.load,
    a.id,
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.id desc) AS INT) numbe,
    sum(numbe + 1) as nmbe2
    from max_num a
    group by a.load
             , a.id        
    order by  a.id
```

Comment: You can not use `numbe` in this select.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  All you are going to end up with is the sum of integers from 2 to n+1, n being the number of rows in your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
select a.load,
       a.id,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.id desc) rn,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.id desc)+1 rn_plus_1
from max_num a
group by a.load, a.id
order by a.load, a.id;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=db3866cd003b196072a057d923385fc9)

But you will have to give us more info about what you want to do...

Comment: Thanks for you help, the issue is after if i do MAX(rn_plus_1)

Comment: Ok, what issue ? Please explain more. Thanks!

Comment: @YassineEssakini do you want MAX or SUM? Your comment here differs from you question.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @YassineEssakini  please analyze here what does sum do, what does max do and what you get back with group by and without group by : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b914eafddeb5aeebc6dc898a582fa8c

Comment: index load id    Result of Max index 
1 a xxx  a ttt
2 a fff  b fff
3 a ttt  c ggg
4 b xxx   
5 b ggf   
6 c ccc   
7 c ggg   
8 b fff

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand this. Please try  to explain in more words and details.

Comment: Hello @YassineEssakini so, what I want from you is to show me like this: I have this data `1, 'test1', 333 | 2, 'test2', 444` and I want to get : `HERE YOU WILL WRITE WHAT YOU WANT TO GET`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866272/sql-call-max-row-number-from-a-temp-table/58872517#58872517