# SQL Oracle.. Update table on latest value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table with name and address. Where address get change sometime.
I need to change the last modified address to each name
The table look like this

```
Name    Address
Samual  123 bixby
Samual  111 adelea
Arfan   12 spadina    
Arfan   22 Spadina
Atesao  Roman Alley
Atesao  Roman Alley
Arfan   12 spadina
```

Output Should be

```
Name    Address
Samual  111 adelea 
Samual  111 adelea
Arfan   12 spadina    
Arfan   12 Spadina
Atesao  Roman Alley
Atesao  Roman Alley
Arfan   12 spadina
```

we need to update full table with latest value

Comment: First we need something to get the latest value, is there any date ? any id ? or something ? Data in table aren't sorted so "latest" value means nothing if you don't provide us a way to get the latest.

Comment: Looks like we need to use pseudo columns for determining time to understand when record was last updated/added.  Details in oracle documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm

Comment: If you don't have any further columns on the table, so nothing which you can use to infer *"latest value"* you should have a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58872517/146325) to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an ID column and determining the order due to this column, consider using :

```
update tab t
   set t.address = (
                    with tt as
                    (
                     select row_number() over (partition by name order by id desc) as rn, 
                            t.*
                       from tab t
                    )
                    select tt.address
                      from tt 
                     where tt.name = t.name
                       and rn = 1
                   )
```

to have latest address per each names through `partition by name` clause within `row_number()` analytic function.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=77e7d386bbaf80c98f54c58cff12e75c)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` but considering that you have some column to identify the latest record. Lets say it is `creation_date`. Also I am ignoring the scenario where 2 users have same name.

> ```
> Merge into your_table t
> Using 
> (select name, 
>         Address,
>         Row_number() over (partition by name order by creation_date desc) as rn
>   From your_table) m
> On (t.name = m.name and m.rn = 1)
> When matched then set t.address = m.address;
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Without row number etc, and assuming you have an id which will let us retrieve the latest value, you can simply achieve what you want with the following query :

```
UPDATE test t SET address = (
  SELECT address 
  FROM test t2 
  WHERE id = (
    SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM test t3 
    WHERE t3.name = t.name 
    GROUP BY t3.name
  )
);
```

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b9e6/3)

Answer (score 1):

use pseudo column SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) 
SQL -

`Merge into table_name t
    Using 
    (select name, 
            Address,
            Row_number() over (partition by name order by SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) desc) as rn
      From table_name) m
    On (t.name = m.name and m.rn = 1)
    When matched then set t.address = m.address;`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (there are already three posted answers to your question).

Here is a less known way. (Why it is "less known" I don't know; many developers believe, incorrectly, that in Oracle you can't update through a join.)

I show a complete example, starting with `create table`. As in other answers, I assume there is a `created_date` column that tells us what "last" means. I also use another feature ignored by many developers - the `FIRST/LAST` aggregate function to find the most recent address.

Notice also the `where` clause in `update` - it's there so that only rows where the address is actually changed are included. That saves on `undo` and `redo` generation.

```
create table t (name, address, created_date) as
  select 'Samual', '123 bixby'  , date '2015-03-24' from dual union all
  select 'Samual', '111 adelea' , date '2018-11-19' from dual union all
  select 'Arfan' , '12 spadina' , date '2015-07-28' from dual union all
  select 'Arfan' , '22 Spadina' , date '2017-03-10' from dual union all
  select 'Atesao', 'Roman Alley', date '2015-09-12' from dual union all
  select 'Atesao', 'Roman Alley', date '2018-01-14' from dual union all
  select 'Arfan' , '12 spadina' , date '2019-05-13' from dual
;

Table T created.

update
  (
    select address, last_address
    from   t join 
             ( select name, 
                      min(address) keep (dense_rank last order by created_date)
                        as last_address
               from   t
               group  by name
             )
             using (name)
  )
set address = last_address
where decode(address, last_address, 0) is null
;

2 rows updated.
```

So, let's see if it worked:

```
select * from t;

NAME   ADDRESS     CREATED_DATE  
------ ----------- --------------
Samual 111 adelea  3/24/2015     
Samual 111 adelea  11/19/2018    
Arfan  12 spadina  7/28/2015     
Arfan  12 spadina  3/10/2017     
Atesao Roman Alley 9/12/2015     
Atesao Roman Alley 1/14/2018     
Arfan  12 spadina  5/13/2019
```

Comment: Seems really great, but just a question, where is the "the FIRST/LAST aggregate function" ? That's quite interesting to be honest !

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your data right, I would suggest a compound trigger to keep this type of information in sync.
Something like this should work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cmp_addr_sync
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_name
COMPOUND TRIGGER 
DECLARE 
  TYPE lt_ChangedItem IS TABLE OF table_name.name%TYPE INDEXED BY VARCHAR2;
  l_tAddrChange lt_ChangedItem;
BEGIN
  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    EXIT WHEN g_bSkipCheck; --THIS IS SOME BOOLEAN ELSEWHERE IN YOUR DB
    IF INSERTING THEN
      l_tAddrChange(:new.name) := :new.addr;
    ELSE
      IF :new.name <> :old.name OR :new.addr <> :old.addr THEN
        l_tAddrChange(:new.name) := :new.addr;
    END IF;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
    l_sIndex table_name.name%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    IF l_tAddrChange.COUNT > 0 THEN
      g_bSkipCheck := TRUE;

      l_sIndex := l_tAddrChange.FIRST;

      WHILE l_sIndex IS NOT NULL LOOP
        UPDATE table_name t
        SET t.addr = l_tAddrChange(l_sIndex)
        WHERE t.name = l_sIndex
        AND t.addr <> l_tAddrChange(l_sIndex);   

        l_sIndex := l_tAddrChange.NEXT(l_sIndex); 
      END LOOP;      

      g_bSkipCheck := FALSE;
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    g_bSkipCheck := FALSE;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END cmp_add_sync;
```

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot you can't use FORALL on a VARCHAR indexed Associative Array.  Also changed some of the code to use %TYPE.